# Getting data from BaseAdapter in Service class

Tags: java, android, android-service, baseadapter

I have a BaseAdapter class using ViewHolders to display a list of checked apps. I store the checked apps with SharedPreferences so the apps that are checked stay checked. What I am trying to achieve is getting the checked apps in my Service Class as ideally store it in an arraylist or something of the sort.

The problem is that the keys are what I used to the get the values are in the BaseAdapter class too and I can't get it from the service class so I had to recreate the methods for getting the list of packages and iterating through with a for loop.

I also cannot checked if the holder checkbox is checked in my Service class since that is done in my BaseAdapter class.

Despite passing the context in BaseAdapter and using getApplicationContext with SharedPreferences I cannot get the list of checked apps in the service class. I am not sure where to turn now. I have tried everything from messing around with static variables, trying everything with getting the context from the BaseAdapter class etc.

Here is my Adapter Class (I have commented where I get the apps which are checked):

```
package com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

//

public class ApkAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    //Pastebin link:  http://pastebin.com/LGRicg4U , http://pastebin.com/c4WfmhMK , http://pastebin.com/gFuuM4dY, http://pastebin.com/4Q7EP9G4
    // http://pastebin.com/Te2g072w,  http://pastebin.com/NLT5iUiA ,

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    List<PackageInfo> packageList;
    ArrayList <String> appchecklist;
    static ArrayList <String> newappchecklist;
    Context mContext;

    Activity context;
    PackageManager packageManager;
    boolean[] itemChecked;


    String PACKAGE_NAME;
    static TinyDB appcheckdb;

    public ApkAdapter(Activity context, List<PackageInfo> packageList,
                      PackageManager packageManager) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.mContext = mContext;

        this.packageList = packageList;
        this.packageManager = packageManager;
        itemChecked = new boolean[packageList.size()];
        appchecklist =  new ArrayList<String>();
        newappchecklist =  new ArrayList<String>();

        appcheckdb = new TinyDB(context);


    }

    public ApkAdapter(Context heartBeat) {

    }


    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView apkName;
        CheckBox ck1;
        TextView packageName;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return packageList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return packageList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_apps, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.apkName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.appname);
            holder.ck1= (CheckBox)convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            holder.packageName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_package);



            convertView.setTag(holder);
            //holder.ck1.setTag(packageList.get(position));

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }



        // ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        final PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) getItem(position);



        Drawable appIcon = packageManager
                .getApplicationIcon(packageInfo.applicationInfo);



        // Make sure to define it again!
        PACKAGE_NAME = packageInfo.packageName;


        final String appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(
                packageInfo.applicationInfo).toString();
        appIcon.setBounds(0, 0, 80, 80);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawables(appIcon, null, null, null);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawablePadding(15);
        holder.apkName.setText(appName);
        //holder.packageName.setText(PACKAGE_NAME);


        holder.ck1.setChecked(false);


        if (itemChecked[position])
            holder.ck1.setChecked(true);
        else
            holder.ck1.setChecked(false);








        for(int i= 0; i<packageList.size(); i++){



            PACKAGE_NAME = packageInfo.packageName;
            //Log.d("lol", PACKAGE_NAME);

            sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PACKAGE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            newappchecklist = appcheckdb.getList("appcheck");

            holder.ck1.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean(PACKAGE_NAME,false));


        }



        // appchecklist has all the checked apps!!!!!

        // it is right here!!!!!!

        if(holder.ck1.isChecked()){
            appchecklist.add(packageInfo.packageName);
            appcheckdb.putList("appcheck", appchecklist);
            for (Object data : appchecklist) {
                Log.e("HUH!?: ",(String) data);
            }


        }


        holder.ck1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(packageInfo.packageName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

                if (holder.ck1.isChecked()) {
                    itemChecked[position] = true;
                    holder.ck1.setChecked(true);
                    editor.putBoolean(packageInfo.packageName, true);


                    editor.apply();

                } else {
                    itemChecked[position] = false;
                    holder.ck1.setChecked(false);
/*                    editor.putBoolean(packageInfo.packageName, false);


                    editor.apply();*/

                }

            }


        });


        return convertView;

    }


    public void check( View convertView, int position){
        final ViewHolder holder;
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.ck1= (CheckBox)convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        final PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) getItem(position);


        PACKAGE_NAME = packageInfo.packageName;



        if(holder.ck1.isChecked()){
            appchecklist.add(packageInfo.packageName);
            appcheckdb.putList("appcheck", appchecklist);
            for (Object data : appchecklist) {
                Log.e("HUH!?: ",(String) data);
            }


        }
    }



    public static ArrayList getArrayList()
    {
        newappchecklist = appcheckdb.getList("appcheck");

        return newappchecklist;
    }






}
```

Here is my service class! I commented where I am trying to get the list:

```
package com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app;

import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class HeartBeat extends Service {



    private static final String TAG = HeartBeat.class.getSimpleName();
    public Timer TIMER;

    String CURRENT_PACKAGE_NAME;


    private static Set<AccessGranted> mAccessGrantedList = new HashSet<AccessGranted>();
    private Set<String> mLockedApps = new HashSet<String>();
    private long lastModified = 0;
    private BroadcastReceiver mScreenStateReceiver;
    private BroadcastReceiver mAccessGrantedReceiver;
    private File mLockedAppsFile;
    private ArrayList newArrayList = null;
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    PackageManager pm = null;
    List<PackageInfo> packageList1 = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();





    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


        startService(new Intent(this, HeartBeat.class));






        pm = getPackageManager();

        List<PackageInfo> packageList = pm
                .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);



        for(PackageInfo pi : packageList) {
            boolean b = isSystemPackage(pi);
            boolean c = isSystemPackage1(pi);

            if(!b || !c ) {
                packageList1.add(pi);
            }

        }

        //TRYING TO GET IT OVER HERE!
        for(int i = 0; i < packageList1.size(); i++) {
            Log.e("hannnnnnn values       ", packageList1.get(i)+ "");
            sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(String.valueOf(packageList1.get(i)), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


        }



        //TRYING TO CHECK IT OVER HERE!

        Map<String, ?> allEntries = sharedPrefs.getAll();
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
            Log.e("map values", entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue().toString());
       }


        // Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " +
        // intent);
        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
        // stopped, so return sticky.
        if (TIMER == null) {

            TIMER = new Timer(true);
            TIMER.scheduleAtFixedRate(new LockAppsTimerTask(), 1000, 250);

            mScreenStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

                private boolean screenOff;

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



                    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                        screenOff = true;
                    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                        screenOff = false;
                    }

                    if (screenOff) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Cancel Timer");
                        TIMER.cancel();
                    } else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Restart Timer");
                        TIMER = new Timer(true);
                        TIMER.scheduleAtFixedRate(new LockAppsTimerTask(), 1000, 250);
                    }
                }
            };

            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
            registerReceiver(mScreenStateReceiver, filter);

            mAccessGrantedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    String action = intent.getAction();
                    String packageName = intent.getStringExtra("packageName");
                    if (action.equals(Constants.ACTION_GRANT_ACCESS) && packageName != null) {
                        AccessGranted ag = new AccessGranted(packageName);
                        mAccessGrantedList.remove(ag);
                        mAccessGrantedList.add(ag);
                    }
                }
            };

            IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(Constants.ACTION_GRANT_ACCESS);
            registerReceiver(mAccessGrantedReceiver, filter2);
        }
        // this.stopSelf();



        //startforeground goes here



        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        startService(new Intent(this, HeartBeat.class));
    }
    private boolean isSystemPackage(PackageInfo pkgInfo) {
        return ((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) ? true
                : false;
    }

    private boolean isSystemPackage1(PackageInfo pkgInfo) {
        return ((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP) != 0) ? false
                : true;
    }



    private class LockAppsTimerTask extends TimerTask {




        @Override
        public void run() {
            ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

            try {
                //List<RecentTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRecentTasks(1, ActivityManager.RECENT_IGNORE_UNAVAILABLE);
                ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager
                        .getRunningTasks(1);
                ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
                String activityOnTop = ar.topActivity.getPackageName();

                // Log.e("activity on Top", "" + activityOnTop);
                //   Log.e(" My package name", "" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName());








//                newArrayList = ApkAdapter.getArrayList();
//                for (Object data : newArrayList) {


// Provide the packagename(s) of apps here, you want to show password activity
                    if ((activityOnTop.contains("com.android.camera")) &&
                            (!activityOnTop.contains(getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                            ))) {  // you have to make this check even better


                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LockScreenActivity.class);
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                        i.putExtra( "", "");
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                //}


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Foreground App", e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }



    }

}
```

Ultimately, I can just tryna get the job done for getting a list of checked apps in my service class. So no matter what whenever I have the service running I have the list of checked apps. Whenever the app opens, re opens, restarts or does whatever, etc.

Help is appreciated. Let me know if there is anything else I can add.

Comment: The text is a little confusing, so one comprehension question first: you are trying to share the ArrayList <String> appchecklist in the BaseAdapter with the HeartbeatService, right? Maybe you could extend the existing Broadcast receiver and send a custom intent that respects this purpose.

Comment: Yes I think you may understand. How can I make it more clear? 

How would that be implemented? trying to understand.

Comment: Please give a hint, if my post was helpful.

Comment: Did it work out for you?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a new database in my SharedPreferences to store only checked apps.

Here is my BaseAdapter class:

```
package com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.R;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

//

public class ApkAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    //Pastebin link:  http://pastebin.com/LGRicg4U , http://pastebin.com/c4WfmhMK , http://pastebin.com/gFuuM4dY, http://pastebin.com/4Q7EP9G4
    // http://pastebin.com/Te2g072w,  http://pastebin.com/NLT5iUiA ,

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefsapp;

    List<PackageInfo> packageList;

    Activity context;
    PackageManager packageManager;
    boolean[] itemChecked;
    HashSet checked;


    String PACKAGE_NAME;

    public ApkAdapter(Activity context, List<PackageInfo> packageList,
                      PackageManager packageManager) {
        super();
        this.context = context;

        this.packageList = packageList;
        this.packageManager = packageManager;
        itemChecked = new boolean[packageList.size()];


    }
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView apkName;
        CheckBox ck1;
        TextView packageName;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return packageList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return packageList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_apps, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.apkName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.appname);
            holder.ck1= (CheckBox)convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            holder.packageName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_package);



            convertView.setTag(holder);
            //holder.ck1.setTag(packageList.get(position));

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }



        // ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        final PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) getItem(position);



        Drawable appIcon = packageManager
                .getApplicationIcon(packageInfo.applicationInfo);



        // Make sure to define it again!
        PACKAGE_NAME = packageInfo.packageName;


        final String appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(
                packageInfo.applicationInfo).toString();
        appIcon.setBounds(0, 0, 80, 80);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawables(appIcon, null, null, null);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawablePadding(15);
        holder.apkName.setText(appName);
        //holder.packageName.setText(PACKAGE_NAME);


        holder.ck1.setChecked(false);


        if (itemChecked[position])
            holder.ck1.setChecked(true);
        else
            holder.ck1.setChecked(false);




        // CHANGE UP EVERYTHING! MAKE THIS SHIT WORK, TIGGA!





        checked = new HashSet();

            PACKAGE_NAME = packageInfo.packageName;
            //Log.d("just here: ", PACKAGE_NAME);

            sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            sharedPrefsapp = context.getSharedPreferences("appdb", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);





        holder.ck1.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean(PACKAGE_NAME,false));







        holder.ck1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editorapp = context.getSharedPreferences("appdb", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

                if (holder.ck1.isChecked()) {

                    itemChecked[position] = true;
                    holder.ck1.setChecked(true);
                    editor.putBoolean(packageInfo.packageName, true);
                    editorapp.putString(packageInfo.packageName, packageInfo.packageName);



                    editor.apply();
                    editorapp.apply();

                   // sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


                } else {
                    itemChecked[position] = false;
                    holder.ck1.setChecked(false);
                    editor.putBoolean(packageInfo.packageName, false);
                    editorapp.remove(packageInfo.packageName);


                    editor.apply();
                    editorapp.apply();
                    //sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);




                }

            }



        });





        return convertView;

    }
}
```

I retrieve the values in service class with key "appdb"

```
package com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app;

import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class HeartBeat extends Service {

    ArrayList<String> packagezList;
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    Map<String, ?> allEntries;
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefsapp;



    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        //startService(new Intent(this, HeartBeat.class));





        sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        sharedPrefsapp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("appdb", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        allEntries= null;
        allEntries = sharedPrefsapp.getAll();
        //prefix = "m";
        packagezList= null;


        packagezList = new ArrayList<String>();




        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
            //Log.e("right key: ", entry.getKey() + "right value: " + entry.getValue().toString()  );
            packagezList.add(entry.getKey());





        }



        for(Object object: packagezList){
            Log.e("YO!", (String) object);
        }

        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        try {
            //List<RecentTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRecentTasks(1, ActivityManager.RECENT_IGNORE_UNAVAILABLE);
            ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager
                    .getRunningTasks(1);
            ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
            String activityOnTop = ar.topActivity.getPackageName();

            // Log.e("activity on Top", "" + activityOnTop);
            //   Log.e(" My package name", "" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName());








            //for (Object data : newArrayList) {

            for(Object object: packagezList){

// Provide the packagename(s) of apps here, you want to show password activity
                if ((activityOnTop.contains((CharSequence) object)) &&
                        (!activityOnTop.contains(getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                        ))) {  // you have to make this check even better


                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LockScreenActivity.class);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    i.putExtra( "", "");
                    startActivity(i);
                }

            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log.e("Foreground App", e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        Intent ishintent = new Intent(this, HeartBeat.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, ishintent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.cancel(pintent);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),150000, pintent);



        return START_STICKY;

}

        // Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " +
        // intent);
        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
        // stopped, so return sticky.

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        Intent ishintent = new Intent(this, HeartBeat.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, ishintent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.cancel(pintent);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),150000, pintent);
        //startService(new Intent(this, HeartBeat.class));

    }


        // this.stopSelf();
        //startforeground goes here



    }
```